# flutter crashing Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I'm facing weird issue that make app crashing in production mode and it's happened once time and don't happened if I try same action I have did , so when try add item in firebase it's crashing and if return try same item in same condition maybe didn't crashed but I have cashed these issues

the first issue

```
/AndroidRuntime( 9758): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.invokeMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$EventObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:451)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$EventObserver.onEvent(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:433)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query.lambda$addSnapshotListenerInternal$2(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:1025)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.Query$$Lambda$3.onEvent(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.lambda$onEvent$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run(Unknown Source:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.0.2:6)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9758):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
I/System.out( 9758): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out( 9758): (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 9758): tagSocket(93) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
D/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 9758): tagSocket(65) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
```

the second issue

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void j.b.a.a.n.a(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$DocumentObserver.a (CloudFirestorePlugin.java:106)
io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$DocumentObserver.a (CloudFirestorePlugin.java:2)
com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.a (DocumentReference.java:87)
com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference$$Lambda$3.a (DocumentReference.java:6)
com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener.a (AsyncEventListener.java:6)
com.google.firebase.firestore.core.AsyncEventListener$$Lambda$1.run (AsyncEventListener.java:6)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
com.google.android.gms.internal.tasks.zzb.dispatchMessage (zzb.java)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7156)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:494)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

another issue

```
E/flutter (24582): [ERROR:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(39)] java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: DrawableResource
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.y.n.n$k0.<init>(Unknown Source:87)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.y.n.n$w.a(Unknown Source:29)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.f.a(Unknown Source:74)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.y.n.i.a(Unknown Source:42)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.y.n.i.a(Unknown Source:123)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.y.n.i.a(Unknown Source:22)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.f.a(Unknown Source:74)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.f.a(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.f.a(Unknown Source:8)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.f.a(Unknown Source:5)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.f.a(Unknown Source:13)
E/flutter (24582):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.b.b(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (24582):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.b.f(Unknown Source:19)
E/flutter (24582):      at com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.b.onMethodCall(Unknown Source:169)
E/flutter (24582):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(Unknown Source:17)
E/flutter (24582):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(Unknown Source:57)
E/flutter (24582):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(Unknown Source:4)
E/flutter (24582):      at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/flutter (24582):      at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:326)
E/flutter (24582):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:181)
E/flutter (24582):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
E/flutter (24582):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/flutter (24582):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
E/flutter (24582):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
E/flutter (24582): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: DrawableResource
E/flutter (24582):      at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:1601)
E/flutter (24582):      at c.c.e.y.n.n$k0.<init>(Unknown Source:34)
E/flutter (24582):      ... 23 more
E/flutter (24582): 
F/flutter (24582): [FATAL:flutter/shell/platform/android/platform_view_android_jni.cc(76)] Check failed: CheckException(env).
```

Comment: If your app is working fine in debug mode, try using --no-shrink option to build the app.

Comment: yes , it's never crashed in debug mode , I will try

Comment: by the way It's crashing in apk --release and build as appbundle

Answer (score 0):

This issue doesn't seem to happen on `cloud_firestore: ^3.1.7`. Try updating the cloud_firestore version that you're using. If that doesn't work, see if proguard is enabled on your Android build. Updating `android.enableR8=false` the Android build's gradle.properties also works to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60211551).