# Flutter: Firestore unavailable error on release mode with minifyEnabled

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I have been experiencing a very strange error. I have been developing an app for some time now (3 years ago) with flutter. I migrated the application to Null safety and from that moment the app started to crash in release mode causing the error

> [cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable.
> This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff.

Everything works fine on debug mode.

I have the following configuration in the related files in the apk compilation in release mode.

android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
...
```

android/app/build.gradle

```
...
android {

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
        }
    }
}
...
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
## Flutter wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.revenuecat.purchases.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
-dontwarn android.**
```

If I change `minifyEnabled false shrinkResources false` to Everything works fine on release mod too, but my app size increase by 27%.

Comment: You're not the only one seeing this. Unfortunately when I reached out to firebase support their answer was that they couldn't help because we use flutter which isn't officially supported - super helpful.

Comment: Here's a couple potentially useful resources:[a disccusion on the flutterfire plugin](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/discussions/5708) and [a deep-dive on the react native plugin which shares a bunch of code with the flutter one](https://medium.com/@chonnaronghanyawongse/coding-diary-why-my-firestore-doesnt-work-2db41fb82121)

Comment: this is very frustrating, my app was in production for a long time without problems until this error. Because of this, my development has stopped. I can't believe this problem has not been solved for more than a year.

Comment: A few questions: (1) what about `minifyEnabled false shrinkResources true`? what about `minifyEnabled true shrinkResources false`? (2) what about `-keep class` and put *everything* there? then try to only `-keep` part of the classes, and so on. finally, you will find out which class should be kept.

Comment: Have you tried updating to a relatively new version of https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore, e.g. 2.5.2 currently? What version are you currently using? Share your pubspec.yaml, sometimes plugins can conflict too.

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? Have the same problem [flutter 2.2.3]

Comment: I had commented `minifyEnabled` (don't have `shrinkResources`), cleaned and reran with `--release`, problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may work for you is go back to using proguard instead of R8, it may be a step back but could help you. For that to happen the configuration of the release should look like:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        useProguard true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
    }
}
```

And maybe you should add to the build gradle that you don't want to use R8:

```
android.enableR8=true
```

Another option would be to look at this file and check for the imports to see if there is maybe a secondary library that you should add to your proguard configuration file: /android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant

You can also check the compilation log to see any errors related to some library (link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15100#issuecomment-474687849)